# I have deleted cache directory from media/catalog/product folder. Now all image paths are giving code 500. How can I regenerate Images?

Tags: product-images

So as the title says I made a mistake and deleted all cached images. And now Magento is confused as image paths are pointing to no files.

I know there is the command to resize images, but it takes forever and crashes if there is unsupported image format or quality. Is there a way to generate these images on the fly, meaning when someone opens a product or category page? Or is there some kind of image cache warmer?

Comment: Have you tried static-content:deploy command?

Comment: Have you tried setup:upgrade then all followed commands again.. ?